# Lightbox Locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

I hit a problem on a website i was doing for work: http://www.dotcomholdings.co.za
the portfolio page has a gallery but the lower images open the lightbox at the top of the page instead of at the users location. i already mailed the themes developer for support but wanted to know in case i need to do this on another site, using jquery how would you set something like this to open at the place you are at on the page? i would like to use jquery but also is there a css property to do the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on how the lightbox is implemented (with regards to CSS positioning). To open at the users location, one can either use `position:fixed`, which will give the **illustion* of opening at the user's location but will cause the lightbox to be fixed relative to the viewport; or listening on the user's scroll position along the document and absolutely positioning the lightbox using that information.

Comment: i believe on the site i mentioned above it uses position:fixed but wont open further down the page, should it not be maybe set to absolute at the users location somehow? the other problem is that with fixed the images are quite large so using fixed would remove the ability to scroll down the image. it needs to open at the viewport and stay at that position while the user scrolls.